# a strategy to learn Japanese

Tags: learning

I want to start learning Japanese but i'm lost i don't know from where to begin, is there anybody knows a good strategy to use?

Comment: A course? A textbook?

Comment: Read Tae Kim's Japanese grammar guide.

Comment: [Language Learning Stack Exchange](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) welcomes questions about learning. However, they would still need to be more focused than the version you submitted here. Why don't you come over? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Start learning hiragana and katakana.